# $ \ f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $ \ f(a,b) = a + b. \sqrt{11}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Let $ \ f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $ \ f(a,b) = a + b. \sqrt{11}$

Is $ \ f$ an injection? Is it a surjection?

My attempt:

It is injective.

$ f(a,b) = f(c,d) \implies a + b. \sqrt{11} = c + d. \sqrt{11} \implies (a-c) + \sqrt{11}(b-d) = 0 \implies a -c = 0$ and $ \ \sqrt{11}(b-d) = 0 \implies a = c$ and $ \ b = d$.

It is not surjective. Notice that $ \ f(a,b) \neq 1\  \forall \ a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. That is $ \ a+ b.\sqrt{11} \neq 1\  \forall \ a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. So $ \ 1 \notin $ image(f). Hence not surjective.

Is my approach and reasoning correct?

Comment: Why does $a-c+\sqrt{11}(b-d)=0$ imply $a-c=0$? Why is $a+b\sqrt{11}$ never equal to $1$?

Comment: Yes , your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Every natural number is in the image of $f$ by just letting $b = 0$.  However, no negative numbers are in the image of $f$.

Comment: $ 0$ is not considered a natural number in the course I'm taking.

Comment: lots of thing you just assumed, instead of that if you just could have assumed that $\sqrt{11}$ can not be written as division of two natural numbers it would be better.

Comment: For surjectivity can I say that since $ \ a,b \in \mathbb{N}, f(a,b) = a + \sqrt{11}.b \ge 1 + \sqrt{11}$. So, $ \ f(a,b) \ne 1$

Comment: What if $a - c = w\ne 0$ and $\sqrt{11}(b-d) = -w\ne 0$?

Comment: Is my argument for surjectivity correct if I say this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answers are correct, but your proofs need some improvement. You jump too quickly to unjustified conclusions, which immediately invalidates the whole "proof".

**Injectivity.** Up to $\color{blue}{(a−c)+\sqrt{11}(b−d)=0}$ everything was fine, but how do you know that $\color{red}{a−c=0}$ and $\color{red}{\sqrt{11}(b−d)=0}$ from there? Two numbers that add up to zero don't have to be zeroes themselves. Yes, it has a lot to do with $a,b,c,d$ being integers and $\sqrt{11}$ being, hmmm… a different kind of number. But you still have to justify each conclusion. Hint: go back to the blue equation and solve it for $\sqrt{11}$.

**Surjectivity.** Same thing: how do you know that $\color{red}{f(a,b)\neq1,\;\forall a,b\in\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. that $\color{red}{a+b\sqrt{11}\neq1,\;\forall a,b\in\mathbb{N}}$? I'm not saying that it's false, because it's actually true. The question is: how do you know that? You have to prove this claim. You can use the same idea: solve for $\sqrt{11}$.

By the way, you can show that this map isn't surjective by a completely different line of reasoning: counting. How many elements are there in the domain $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I think *invalidates* its a little bit harsh. The proof is actually valid, only that considering the kind of excercise the OP's asking, it is clearly necessairy to include that kind of argumentation. And that's why I find the rest of the answer great!

Comment: For surjectivity  can I say that since $ \ a,b \in \mathbb{N}, f(a,b) = a + \sqrt{11}.b \ge 1 + \sqrt{11}$. So, $ \ f(a,b) \ne 1$

Comment: @zipirovich. For injectivity, when I solve for $ \ \sqrt{11}$ I get $ \ \sqrt{11} = \frac{-(a-c)}{b-d}$. Now what?

Comment: Zipirovich. Nice!

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado: Thank you for your comment! Yes, I agree that `invalidates` was a poor word choice. Oh well, nobody's perfect... :-)

Comment: @PeterSzilas: Thank you!

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel: Regarding your follow-up question on surjectivity. Yes, you can say that. And that would be precisely the explanation that was missing in your original post. Fill it in there, and you have a perfect and complete proof! As an additional exercise, however, note that if the original question had $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ as the domain, then this argument wouldn't work.

Comment: @zipirovich could you please help with the injective part. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel: Regarding your follow-up question on injectivity. If $b-d\neq0$, then we can divide both sides by $b-d$ to obtain $\sqrt{11}=\frac{c-a}{b-d}$. Since $a,b,c,d$ are all integers, the right-hand side is a rational number, but $\sqrt{11}$ isn't. Therefore, $b-d=0$, giving us the desired conclusion.

Comment: @zipirovich Oh I see. That makes a lot of sense. Btw I was working on a similar question. The function was $ \ f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ via $ \ f(a,b) = 5^{a}. 7^{b}$. Can I say that its not surjective since $ \  f(a,b) = 5^{a}. 7^{b} \ge 5^{1}.7^{1} = 35$ so any natural number between $1$ and $ 34$ is not in the image of $ \ f$?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel: Yes, you sure can -- it's a perfectly correct explanation.